# Power BI- replacing user ID with user name

Tags: replace, powerbi, dax

I have columns i.e: user id that is corresponding to name and transactional data- fromUserid and toUserid (plz see the attached image). I want to replace the from and to userid with name. Is there any way to do in power BI. I replace the values by creating new conditional column, but unmatched values shows null.
Thanks[Please see the image for clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4BJk.png)

Comment: Can you share the conditional statement you are using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option you do some transformation in your **Power Query Editor**. The steps are given below-

considering your base table name is: **map_user**

**Step-1:** Duplicate your table **map_user** and rename it as **map_user_distinct**

**Step-2:** Just keep you column "name" and "user id" and remove other columns from the new table "map_user_distinct"

**Step-3:** Now keep distinct rows as shown in the below image. You can also see the output after removing duplicate rows in the image.

[image]

**Step-4:** Now select your base table "map_user" and select option "merge queries" as shown below image-

[image]

And now configure the merging properties as below-

[image]

This will return a Table per row.

**Step-5:** Now expand the table as below and keep only column "name"

[image]

Now rename the new column as "from user name" and the output will be as below-

[image]

Finally, repeat **Step-4:** and **Step-5:** considering the column "to user id" and you will get your desired output.

Comment: Thanks Rabbani. Appreciate.

Comment: Yeah that's perfect. Thanks

Comment: there is a Gray Tick mark on left top of my answer. Click that for accepting the answer. And on top of that there is one up and one down arrow. Click the up arrow for a up vote. @Paper.

Comment: Hi @mkRabbani, trying to calculate datediff (in PowerBI) from two datetime columns in hrs excluding weekend and non-business hrs. Is there any solution. Your help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you have post for that? Give me the link then.

Comment: Hi @mkRabbani, Thanks. here is the question link i posted. appreciate.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70687511/how-to-calculate-time-difference-between-two-datetime-columns-in-hours-excluding

Comment: I have seen the post. It can be achieved in Power query but need some time as need numbers of steps and logic to think about. I will try to come back later.

Comment: thanks appreciate. I find perfection in your solutions. looking forward.

Comment: Hi @Paper, check the answer I posted in your new question.