# how to calculate time difference between two datetime columns in hours excluding weekends and business hours in power bi?

Tags: powerbi

Hi wondering how to calculate time difference between two datetime columns (ENDDATETIME - STARTDATETIME) in hours (accounting mins and secs also) excluding weekends (Sat and Sun) and non-business hours ( between 5 pm to 8 am) in power bi ? Thanks

| ID | STARTDATETIME | ENDDATETIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 102 | 2019-11-24 13:46:48.000 | 2019-12-16 04:51:11.000 |
| 105 | 2019-10-17 12:18:18.000 | 2019-10-31 04:50:57.000 |
| 108 | 2019-11-30 10:56:37.000 | 2019-12-04 04:51:19.000 |
| 110 | 2019-10-25 17:31:29.000 | 2019-11-20 04:51:11.000 |
| 112 | 2019-11-25 16:03:02.000 | 2019-11-25 17:51:04.000 |
| 115 | 2019-11-04 14:12:09.000 | 2019-11-07 09:00:02.000 |

Answer (score 0):

Rather then posting the **Power Query** code here, I would prefer you download the sample power BI file from [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zCcslfWF4wHC43t9Nln-8TPvbbYvx_3T/view?usp=sharing) and check the steps for achieving the desired output.

Some steps might have possibilities to combine, but I keep them separate so that you can visualize the changes in each step easily.

This same can be achieved using DAX but I guess the code will be more complex. Please let me know if you face any issue.